Breaking New Ground
This is part 60 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
This crossword is a combination of straight crosswords clues, cryptic clues and printer’s devilry. In five cases, the answer is too long to fit the grid and one letter must be removed. Letter removals produce real words found in the UKACD. In these five clues, highlight one letter of the clue at the same position as the deleted letter in the answer. For example, if the fourth letter of the answer was removed, highlight the fourth letter of the clue.
Today I have visited yet another country for the first time, to see an ancient city peppered with thousands of temples, stupas, pagodas, monasteries and ruins. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

Solve on Penpa+
Straight →
1. To bankrupt, exhaust, drain
4. More adorable
7. Compete using lances
9. An American generation of writers, including Allen Ginsberg and Jack Kerouac
10. What Moses parted (2 wds.)
14. Using a rubber, wipe off
16. Sink, droop
Cryptic ↘
2. Truly allowed to quarter soldier
3. Poked fun at Chas and Eddie?
4. Audibly signal the time for coffee in King's work
5. Eurovision winners, one member short, joined by rap artist, retreated to recording studio famously located on this road?
8. Some thousand dollars are used in this country (abbr.)
13. Centre of oasis rimmed by tropical trees in songbook?
15. Dialled and governed with the head of government
Printer's devilry ↗
6. What makes a Nora nastier than a grapefruit?
7. The Battle o' flan din 1916 was fought off the coast of Denmark
11. They deemed my id rib lean, dim, practical
12. Do Nate, Des, Sue can be used in a corneal transplantation to restore a patient's vision
16. Intense heat caused the worker stop, er, oak in GT, heir shirts
17. My Nissan is just as nice as any 100,000D ol' man car
18. Saturn, ig, I ant, as opposed to planets like Mars which are "rocky"

Gladys will return in Top of the World.

Gladys is in:

 Bagan, an ancient city in Myanmar.

 The answer is found by highlighting letters in the clues as given in the instructions. The highlighted letters are indicated in parentheses in the detailed ansers below. The five clues that contribute to the answer are S1, S9, S14, C15 and PD17.

The completed grid:

 

Straight

 1. To (b)ankrupt, exhaust, drain — DEPLETE → DELETE (B)
 4. More adorable — CUTER
 7. Compete using lances — JOUST
 9. An (A)merican generation of writers, including Allen Ginsberg and Jack Kerouac — BEAT → BAT (A)
 10. What Moses parted (2 wds.)  — RED SEA
 14. Usin(g) a rubber, wipe off  — ERASE → ERAS (G)
 16. Sink, droop — SAG

Cryptic

 2. Truly allowed to quarter soldier — LEGIT = LE(GI)T
 3. Poked fun at Chas and Eddie? — TEASED = TEAS + ED
 4. Audibly signal the time for coffee in King's work — CUJO sounds like "Cue Joe"
 5. Eurovision winners, one member short, joined by rap artist, retreated to recording studio famously located on this road? — ABBEY = ABB(a) + YE<
 8. Some thousand dollars are used in this country (abbr.) — USA = (tho)USA(nd)
 13. Centre of oasis rimmed by tropical trees in songbook? — PSALMS = (oa)S(is) in P.ALMS
 15. Di(a)lled and governed with the head of government — RANG = RAN + G(overnment) → RAG (A)

Printer's devilry

 6. What makes an oran[GE T]astier than a grapefruit?
 7. The Battle of [JUT]land in 1916 was fought off the coast of Denmark
 11. They deemed my id[EAS TER]rible and impractical
 12. Donated e[YE TI]ssue can be used in a corneal transplantation to restore
     a patient's vision
 16. Intense heat caused the workers to per[SPIRE S]oaking their shirts
 17. My (N)issan is just as nice as any 100,000 Dol[LAR GER]man car — LAGER (N)
 18. Saturn i[S A GAS] giant, as opposed to planets like Mars which are "rocky"

